# Claim based multiplattform (single sign on)

Tags: php, .net, security, cloud, single-sign-on

Is there a "single sign on" system which works with .NET (maybe WIF), JAVA and PHP?

Is Kerberos a possible solution? I'm new to that topic and would need some hints for google for them. I would like to use it in a cloud infrastructure with mixed plattforms where SOS is needed

Thanks a lot
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a SAML / WS-Federation solution would give yuo SSO across multiple platforms. WIF would be the library to use for .NET based apps. You will have to use equivalents of WIF in the other ones.

WIF is in essence a library to parse, validate and deal with Security Tokens.

In addition to all that you will need an STS: a service that is able to issue security tokens that applications trust.

For a general introduction on the subject take a look at this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359101.aspx

Comment: I read some stuff about SAML. Is it also the right tool for a cloud cluster scenario? E.g. i have
www.mypage.com, order.mypage.com, buy.mypage.com, productinformation.mypage.com which are 4 clusters (each has several servers). Is there a huge overhead with SAML if i make lots of Web Service calls? In a cluster - should i create a session on each and work with "session awareness load balancing"? My concern: if every webservice call has to validate the ticket at a 3rd party (e.g. Kerberos machine) - it is going to be very slow - isnt it?

Comment: Yes, it's one tool to solve this. Web sites and Web services operate slightly different, but in general you wouldn't do all the token negotiation on each request. If it is a website, the token is serialized and kept in cookies or session until it expires.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent some time on reading and found ADFS 2.0 and WIF quite helpfull. I have to check if ADFS 2.0 works with Java and PHP (actually it uses SAML 2.0 under the hood it should)